# How to test DialogFlow FB Messenger integration in different languages outside the DialogFlow simulator?

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is there a way to test DialogFlow agent in a non-default language in Facebook Messenger or using another way that is not the DialogFlow's own simulator (console.dialogflow.com)?

Facebook Messenger integration works great in a default language, but when I try to talk in a non-default language DialogFlow keeps responding in a default language. I tried changing Facebook interface language to a non-default language and it is still the same problem.

I also tried using DialogFlow's Web Demo, but it looks like that support only the default language too. Response about that from Google representative is here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/RPVrna1_Yoc